# Application of Quantum Physics Dynamics in real life

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, quantum-electrodynamics

I'm currently reading a book about Quantum Physics. I was wandering what kind of effects do we see in every day life which can be explained by the equations of quantum dynamics?
I'm trying to connect between the equations and effect I'm familiar with (e.g. application of Quantum Physics in technologies such as MRI)

Than you.

Comment: You might be interested in Sabine Hossenfelder's latest blogpost ["It’s not just a theory for small things"](http://backreaction.blogspot.com/2020/09/understanding-quantum-mechanics-6-its.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MRI is a good example.  The human body is largely composed of water (H2O), and the hydrogen nuclei - protons - are particles with spin 1/2.  These spin 1/2 protons are then subjected to a large static external magnetic field which sets up a "preferred" orientation, which you can call the "z-axis."  Furthermore, this also establishes discrete energy levels.  If the spins are aligned with the field, they are in the lower energy state, and if they are aligned in the opposite sense, they are in the higher energy state.

I hope this helps.